# Prevent default select of current day with Ant Calendar

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying to create custom Calendar based on Ant Calendar.
Ant Calendar adds class '.ant-fullcalendar-selected-day' by default for current day, but how to avoid it?

https://codesandbox.io/s/r809w9

I need to prevent adding class '.ant-fullcalendar-selected-day' for the first render.

Of course, I could override styles something like this:

```css
.ant-fullcalendar-selected-day .ant-fullcalendar-value {
  color: unset;
  background: unset;
}
```

But I'll not be able to use selecting days after that anymore

Comment: you can override it using styles or what is your expected output?.

Comment: I'd override this class inside global.scss, but I need to use it for selecting day. I just need to prevent selecting current day as default

Comment: in useEffect, document.querySelector(".ant-fullcalendar-today").classList.remove("ant-fullcalendar-selected-day");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found this easy solution after investigation

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const selectedDay = document.querySelector('.ant-fullcalendar-selected-day')
    if (selectedDay) {
      selectedDay.classList.remove('ant-fullcalendar-selected-day')
    }
  }, [])
```

Comment: I think it is a reasonable solution and since you are removing the class only after the initial first render it will not prevent the user from selecting a day.

Comment: Also, you might already know it but just laying it out here for others that this solution might just remove the visual distinction but within the component, the current day will still be the 'selected day'.

Comment: @Harshay Buradkar
 Yeah, you're right - it's just visual, but I needed exactly this effect. Thanks fro your comments